# how i can click on <td in <table> with WatiN

Tags: watin

I want the mouse move on line that contained onclick method

and Click on it

How i can do this ???

```
<table width="100%" class="FormTable" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="100" background="/images/tabimage/nrm_bg.gif" nowrap="" onmouseover="this.style.cursor = 'pointer';" onmouseout="this.style.cursor = 'default';" onclick="__doPostBack('HstUnitExchangeLetterSendEdit$tabControl1','1')">

<div class="Normal">
---text---main info
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is this yaar
have checked my previously given code and its working fine on the html page given by you

```
Browser browser = SetupBrowser();
browser.GoTo("file:///C:/Users/vbhadauria/Desktop/New%20folder/mail.html");
var tablecell = browser.TableCell(Find.By("background", "/images/tabimage/sel_bg.gif"));
tablecell.Click();
browser.WaitForComplete();
```

You can also check check it on local machine only.

Comment: what is setupbrowser() i define browser like this browser = new ie() when i copy line 1 the visual studio sho error for setupbrowser()

Comment: you can use your own method i use an IE helper class.

Comment: dear Rex, do u have facebook account ? i want add u to in list of my best friends

Comment: @SajadZarepour Same email id on which you sent mail

Comment: Can u test in local machine with my html file and fill textbox txtCode ? with ex, 12345

Comment: var txttextfeildname = browser.TextField(Find.ById("HstUnitExchangeLetterSendEdit_txtNo"));  txttextfeildname.TypeText("your text as string");

Comment: i edit text id and worked and select textbox but can not type anything or clear , and visual studio error

Comment: @SajadZarepour keep on experimenting Watin has a lot more to learn

Comment: i want to click on table cell element , can i use this code find.by("id" , "HstUnitExchangeLetter_txtid")); i use this code bu not worked, and use find.byId("HstUnitExchangeLetter_txtid") but not worked

Comment: Can u click on a table cell in my html file. open html file and see top of page left corner see 4 item. if i want click on these item what do i do ?

Comment: var tablecell2 = browser.TableCell(Find.By("Name", "HstUnitExchangeLetterSendEdit$ctl00$formSaveButton"));
 tablecell2.Click();
browser.WaitForComplete();    Not Worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Table cell like this

```
var tableCell = browser.TableCell(Find.By("background", "/images/tabimage/nrm_bg.gif"));

//Then click on it
tableCell.Click();
//Wait for browser to load properly
browser.WaitForcomplete();
```

Comment: Are you sure this code is true? and worked? do you test this code for your projects ? and find by background is enough ? and if this nrm_bg.gif repeated for 2 or 3 link ???  because the two table existed not need table id FormTable ?

Comment: Not Worked !  can anyone help ?

Comment: @SajadZarepour Can you provide give me the website's url for this. i can give a better answer if i can see the html sructure.

Comment: dear Rex , in my office , we have One web application office auotimation in interanet Not internet, but this Application writed by Asp and contained farsi language in text lables that maybe you dont anderstand but if you want I can send u the source of one page that I need it for WatiN project, can u send me ur Email address ?

Comment: @SajadZarepour you can send it to vinay199129@gmail.com

Comment: One more thing you can check var tableCell = browser.TableCell(Find.By("Attributename", "AtributeValue")); in the quickwatch mode, and try the attibutename and value exactly same as they are in your website.

Comment: Or if this particular div "<div class="Normal">" will always be inside this td and there is no other div with this class. then you can find the td by using the parent property browser.Div(Find.ByClass("")).Parent;