# Change the value of an html table cell using C#

Tags: c#, html

I'm trying to navigate automatically through a website by filling text fields, clicking buttons, etc. I've been using the WatiN C# library to do so with success, however I can't seem to change the value of a html table cell defined this way :

```
<TABLE class=table1>
<TBODY>
    <TR class=dis>
        <TD> rowSpan="1" colSpan="1"
        Famille
        <INPUT name="familySearch" onkeyup="toMaj(document.forms[0],'familySearch');changeFormEltFocus(3, 'eng.facLab');" onfocus=onKeyBack() maxLength=3 size=3 value="AAA"></input>
        <A onclick="popupFamily('RFOS');" tabIndex=-1 href="#"><IMG border=0 hspace=4 alt=" " src="/ppm/images/picto_loupe.gif" align=absMiddle></A>
        </TD>
    </TR>
</TBODY>
```

**What I've tried already :**

- Treat it as a textfield using Watin

  browser.TextField(Find.ByName("familySearch")).Focus();
  browser.TextField(Find.ByName("familySearch")).TypeText("AAA");

(with and without the focus) I got the error "An unhandled exception of type 'WatiN.Core.Exceptions.ElementNotFoundException' occurred in WatiN.Core.dll Additional information: Could not find INPUT (hidden) or INPUT (password) or INPUT (text) or INPUT (textarea) or TEXTAREA element tag matching criteria: Attribute 'name' equals 'familySearch'"

- Using a function that looked promising :

  browser.Table(Find.ByClass("table1")).TableRows[0].TableCells[0].SetAttributeValue("AAA", "X82");

I got an error saying I couldn't access the cell

I think WatiN doesn't allow me to do it, so do you have any idea to help me achieve that task ? 
I'm not good at programming so I apologize if I'm not being clear. Thanks !

**EDIT :**

I've found the reason why I couldn't access it. It has nothing to do with the fact that it is a table, it's just that it was in an iframe.
I just needed to start search with " browser.Frame(Find.ByName..."

Comment: It's helpful if you explain what you've tried and how / why it failed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've added the things I tried to my post.
Regarding the possible duplicate, it's not about accessing a table cell, which is what troubles me.

Comment: James Thorpe, you think I should be able to access it using the standard "browser.TextField(Find.ByName..." ?

Comment: browser.TableCell ? This helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925667/how-i-can-click-on-td-in-table-with-watin ?

Comment: I tried and click the cell, but it's not even found :

An unhandled exception of type 'WatiN.Core.Exceptions.ElementNotFoundException' occurred in WatiN.Core.dll

Additional information: Could not find TD element tag matching criteria: Attribute 'name' equals 'familySearch' at ...

Do you know why there isn't any function that allows to type into a cell ? Just click on it or read it.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, you are not trying to type into a cell... you are trying to type into an 'input' that is in a cell.

Comment: Have you tried browserinstance.TextField(t => t.Name == "familySearch").Value = "CBA"; ?

Comment: Indeed I'm trying to type into an 'input'. Nevertheless what you suggested didn't work, I still get the error : "Could not find INPUT (hidden) or INPUT (password) or INPUT (text) or INPUT (textarea) or TEXTAREA element tag ". Thank you for trying though !